# Get like count from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

like my title said it, I just want to get the number of like of a facebook page. But I'm struggling because It seems to be that I've to have an token access to have this details, and to have this details i've to create a Facebook App... And to do that I've to submit some details like screenshot of my app.. But I've none, I'd just like to have the counter details.

So my questions is, am I doing this wrong or I have to do an App just to get so poor details ?

In case of, this is my App ID : 854201018003819

Thanks you !

Comment: You need an access token, and for that you need an app. But you don’t necessarily have to submit your app for review; if you are only using that app yourself, then review is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna get the likes count of any Facebook page then run the below url.

`graph.facebook.com/{username}?access_token={token}`

You'll see the result in last or second last line.

Also if you don't have any app for access token then you can use other applications such as http://goo.gl/jZ7Nyl

Lemme know if I can help you with anything else.

Comment: In a kind of way this helped me. I found which page give me the Access token, so you don't have to submit an APP to get this token. Cheers !